# Repeated background overlapping

Tags: css

I have a background pattern which can be easily repeated. The problem is i have a shadow to the bottom of the background and to the right of the background. How do I repeat such an image? I thought I can probably cut the piece from the right and overlap that right shadow. Or using whole image is the only solution?
[image]

Comment: I would like to have a solution without changing HTML markup. I have one div only.

Comment: Solid color used in the picture is just a demo. I have a pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use  `box-shadow` css property to apply the shadows for your element instead repeat an image for the shadows also. You can use the following to make the shadows like your example:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000; /* FF3.5+ */
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000; /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000; /* Opera 10.5, IE9 */
```

Of course, as you see these properties doesn't support internet explorer 8 and below but you can use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/), a script that bring you some css3 properties to internet explorer. Is something that I often use.

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/iquso3

An alternative is to use a jquery solution from the [many](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/shadow) that exist.

Answer (score 0):

For a background, using a whole image is the only solution, so you'll need separate images to do this on a flexible sized box.

You can probably keep the html and add the shadown using css, or by dynamically inserting extra divs using javascript/jquery.

Comment: It is not flexible size. It's fixed size. The only problem is that the whole basckground image size is huge.

Comment: Same applies then. If you don't want to create such a large image, you'll need to find another solution. You cannot use a part of an image as a repeating background.